# Error when using single quote with sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement so that I can script out view creation using if not exists with `sp_executesql` but the statement is giving me errors due to the single quotes around 1 in my last where statement.  Is there any way around this?

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYS.objects WHERE NAME = 'vw_JeopardyAlertDetails' AND    TYPE = 'V')
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_JeopardyAlertDetails]
AS 
    SELECT Main.TicketNumber, TS.TicketStateDesc, Main.ApptEnd, ISNULL(C.FirstName, '') AS FirstName, ISNULL(C.LastName, '') AS LastName, ISNULL(Main.CustomerID, '') 
                   AS CustomerID, Main.ApptID, Main.ID, Main.TicketType
    FROM  (SELECT s.TicketState, s.TicketID AS ID, s.ApptEnd, dbo.Ticket.TicketNumber, dbo.Ticket.TimeOpened, dbo.Ticket.CreatedBy, dbo.Ticket.ReportedBy, 
                                  dbo.Ticket.ModifiedBy, dbo.Ticket.ChangedBy, dbo.Ticket.Priority, dbo.Ticket.ServingArea, dbo.Ticket.StructureLink, dbo.Ticket.CustomerID, 
                                  dbo.Ticket.TicketCategory, dbo.Ticket.TicketCode, s.ApptStart, s.TicketType, s.CanReschedule, ISNULL(s.ID, 0) AS ApptID
                   FROM   dbo.Schedule AS s INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.Ticket ON s.TicketID = dbo.Ticket.ID
                   WHERE (s.TicketState IN
                                      (SELECT DISTINCT TicketState
                                       FROM   dbo.AlertJeopardyTicketState
                                       WHERE (IsJeopardyState = '1'))) AND (s.ApptEnd >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) + ' ' + dbo.GetJeopardyStartTime())) 
                                  AND (s.ApptEnd <= GETDATE())) AS Main LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   dbo.Customer AS C ON Main.CustomerID = C.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   dbo.TicketStatus AS TS ON Main.TicketState = TS.ID
    GO' ;
    ELSE PRINT N'vw_JeopardyAlertDetails ALREADY EXISTS'
GO
```

Comment: Why do u use `sp_executesql` to create view instead of direct command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to double up those quotes in your Sql  @statement, e.g.

```
ISNULL(C.FirstName, '')
```

needs to be

```
ISNULL(C.FirstName, '''')
```

Simplified [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d695/96)

Comment: Also in concatenation: `, GETDATE(), 111) + ' ' + dbo.GetJeopardyStartTime()))`

Comment: Thank you Stuart and Goat.  I actually figured this out a couple of minutes after asking.  I've been staring at a screen for too long.

Comment: @Yuriy's question still intrigues - the only reason why I would use dynamic sql to create views would be if there was a dynamic component to it e.g. if I wanted to decide on the name of the view at run time. This doesn't appear to be the case?

Comment: I am compiling a database upgrade script that can be used from software version to version.